# ios Jailbroken device link static library to third party apps

Tags: ios, static-libraries, jailbreak

First of all I am new to Jailbroken device development . I heard by jailbreaking the iOS device we will get the root access . I have a  static library which performs some actions on the apps according to server commands if its bind with my static library . For binding static library I need to send the lib file to customers and they have to attach that in their code so its causing delay and problems for me . My question is can we link this static library to all the apps in an iOS Jailbroken device without being attached to the code by customers (Someway all the apps which I opens in the device should have my static library attached ) .Please help me  they don't want to put that app to AppStore so Jailbroken is fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but this sounds like you need a tweak, which should hook a convenient method from UIKit that occurs at application start and calls the appropiate code from your library.

Sorry I am not able to be more specific, I just wanted to give you an idea for a direction. The way I see it, you can hook for example UIApplicationMain(...) function which is called only once when the app is started, and there add your  code, in a block executed on a dispatch_queue, not to mess with the UI... just a thougth.